# Android - How do I maintain the correct event sequencing in recording an I/O transaction?

Tags: android, multithreading, io

I have a program which allows Android tablets (Nexus 7 2012 and Samsung Galaxy 10.1)  to interact with a Forth system on PIC.  Communication between the two is via Bluetooth using a variant of the Bluetooth Service sample app. The basic arrangement is working, but I have extended it to access commands saved on the tablet as text files.  Files may contain multiple lines of code.  The application structure is a main activity which simply provides access to various Fragments - in particular TerminalFragment for the entry of command strings using a soft keyboard with a TextView to display commands and replies.  Bluetooth comms are via a separate class BtService in its own file, with file handling through a separate FileListActivity.

Each command line entered from the tablet should return an acknowledgement (either result + "- ok! " if good, or an error message if not. There are no problems if a single line is entered from the keyboard, or if a single-line file is used.  If I use a multi-line file, each line is sent separately and I expect to see the response to that line displayed on the terminal immediately after the command line - so that any errors etc are associated with the relevant command.

For example,

```
1 2 + U.     (command)
3            (result) 
-ok!         (acknowledgement)
```

However, the display shows all commands in a file as a block followed by the responses, also as a block:

```
1 2 + U.
3 4 + U.
5 6 + U.
3
- ok!
7
- ok!
B
- ok!
```

Logcat shows that the response to each command line is received immediately it has been sent, and prior to the next command line being transmitted. The replies are forwarded to the main activity through a message handler. However, the main activity does not handle these messages immediately but only after all the lines in the file have been sent and acknowledged.

As I don't know a lot about the details of the interactions between the message service and target activities, can anyone explain what is going on and if there is a simple fix that would allow me to do what I want? I have tried using a flag to hold off sending a line command until the acknowledgement to the last has been received, but this could potentially cause a lock-up if the target device doesn't react - which is likely in the final applications.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find a way to get what I want.  By putting all transactions into the message queue system in the correct sequence, they are eventually dealt with in the same sequence.

But I have to take a line of text entered through my "terminal" fragment, pass it to the main activity and then to the Bluetooth service. From here it is passed back to the main activity as a message, and then finally back into the terminal fragment for display - seems to be somewhat roundabout!